# replace powershell command inside a batch

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a batch file to change a csv file to a txt file and I need to "embed" the powershell commands above into this batch file. In this case, I can't use a .ps1 file....

```
${c:\file.csv} = ${c:\file.csv} -replace ','
${c:\file.csv} = ${c:\file.csv} -replace '"', ''
```

Can you help me, please?

Thanks in advance,
Fabi

Comment: Why can't you use a .ps1 file?  Try putting `set-executionpolicy remotesigned` at the top of the .ps1 script.  If you're calling it within a batch file, call it as `powershell ".\powershellscript.ps1"` if it's in the same directory.

Comment: I can't use 2 files to do this job, because it will be starter from a end user and works with a temporary directories. I'll send it every time he have to use it Thank you very much, Fabi.

Comment: in the resulkting text file how is the data separated - tabs or spaces? also what OS will the batch file be run on

Comment: Hi! The resulting text file is separated by spaces and the OS will be win 7.

Answer (score 0):

if you're allowed to have a powershell process open, you can put this in a batch file

```
echo . | powershell -executionpolicy bypass -command "&{ read-host 'do powershell stuff here' }"
```

Comment: Hi!
I've tryed your suggestion, but I'm still have an error message: Set-Content isn't a internal command. This is the command line that I used : echo . | powershell -executionpolicy bypass -command "&{ read-host '(Get-Content $csv="\\ip_address\folder\file.csv") -replace "," -replace '"', '' | Set-Content \\ip_address\folder\fileOut.txt'}" .... can you tell me what I'm doing wrong, please? Thank you very much, Fabi